# Center page on Blackberry for mobile site

Tags: css, blackberry, mobile, center

I have a mobile site that works on every browser I test it with. Though on a Blackberry the entire page seems to align to the left rather than in the center.

Is there a specific way to make it align to the middle like everything else? Can you use conditionals the way you would with IE? Do I need to target the body tag instead?

At the moment it's just a simple margin: 0 auto; - Any help is appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: I'm not entirely sure, which is why I'm not voting to close, but you *might* find http://doctype.com a better resource for answering this question.

Comment: Doctype is: <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//WAPFORUM//DTD XHTML Mobile 1.0//EN" "http://www.wapforum.org/DTD/xhtml-mobile10.dtd"> Which is what we usually use for mobile sites, we've never had to worry about Blackberries before.

Comment: What sort of Blackberry is it?  Most models, by default, don't apply any CSS.

Answer (score 1):

I originally stumbled upon this question by asking the same thing, then I figured out a solution (for my particular case), which I thought I'd share. (Note: my site left-aligned in Safari on my iPhone.)

I divided my site into sections, some of which were set to min-width: 1140px while others to 960px. With left and right margins set to auto, everything appeared centered on all desktop browsers, as they should.

However, those sections that were narrower were left-aligned on mobile, so I simply wrapped them in a div with width: 100%, min-width: 1140px (or your widest section), margin: 0 auto; and everything aligned normally on mobile :)

Answer (score -1):

Try wrapping the container/content you want centered in another  element with text-align set to center. E.g.

<div style="text-align:center;width:100%;">
    <div id="myContent" style="width:50%;"> </div>
  </div>